# What's the best book to read to understand this site?

Tags: betting-strategy, poker-theory, terminology

I've always been a decent poker player. I typically win and understand probabilities and money management from life experience and trading. I'm an engineer, so I naturally approach things with a certain degree of rigor.

But I'm reading this site and realizing that there's a quantum level of "poker technology" that I never knew existed. What sites or books would you recommend to at least get the terminology and fundamental concepts that are discussed here?

Thanks!

Comment: See here: http://poker.stackexchange.com/q/486/309

Comment: http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/

Comment: a Villain... :)

Comment: Do you mean understand this site or understand poker terminology?technology?

Comment: I guess I mean poker terminology and technology.  But this site is the only place where I've ever encountered what's here.  So, both.  :-)

Comment: It's a little against the idea of _this_ site, but http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/69/micro-stakes-pl-nl/ has people many FAQs and general strategy posts that should get you bootstrapped.

Comment: @LeeGrey I take it back; the best place to understand this site is probably to post questions to this site.  If we could bootstrap the site itself with a decent corpus of questions and answers, it may become more useful than it currently is.

Comment: If that's the case, the place to start is with a glossary of terms and abbreviations/acronyms.  It's almost unintelligible to a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are interested in texas holdem(Most common type of poker card game)

Your selection of learning materials depends on type of game you play(Fixed/No limi cash, Heads up, SNG, MTT)

I found nice [list](http://www.thepokerbank.com/tools/books/) of best books.
 Especially Moshman, Miller, Sklansky are authors who invented a lot of poker terminology. Their explanation of poker decision process and different strategy concepts are based on science methods!
( == math proofs)

You should also definitevely check following links:

http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/

http://www.pokerstrategy.com/home/

(referal link : http://www.pokerstrategy.com/#u56DJM Not sure if its allowed :-/)

http://www.husng.com/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out the NL forums on twoplustwo:
http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/7/no-limit-holdem/

Most of the decent online players matured there.
It's an enormous source of knowledge, some of it is pure gold.
You'll find some incredibly knowledgeable and helpful people.

I highly recommend this collection of forum posts / articles. These are the finest writings about the basics and more advanced concepts of the game, it will put you lightyears ahead of micro / small stakes competition.
I remember when i first came by this around 2008, I got so hooked :)
Have fun!

http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/69/micro-stakes-pl-nl/unl-archives-memorable-strategy-threads-430489/